# Why do the complex gains of an RLC circuit add to 1?

Tags: electric-circuits, electrical-resistance, capacitance, inductance

I'm working through a class on differential equations and the following came up and it was pretty neat, but no explanation was given.

The complex gains for the differential equations for the voltage drops across a resistor, capacitor, and inductor add to 1.  The only explanation given was that this reflects Kirchhoff's Rule.  Can anyone expound on this please?

Comment: electronics.stackexchange.com would also be a nice place to post this

Comment: All three are in series.

Answer (score 2):

It doesn't really matter what is the nature of the elements composing the network (they should be linear, though), nor their number. The derivation is quite straightforward.

In the following I assume to be in the sinusoidal steady-state regime, and I represent voltages with the associated complex phasors.

If there is a series of $n$ elements with overall voltage $V$, Kirchhoff's voltage law (KVL) states that

$$V = V_1+\ldots+V_n,$$

where $V_1,\ldots V_n$ are the voltages across each element.

If you now define the gain with respect to each element as

$$G_k = \frac{V_k}{V},\qquad k = 1,\ldots,n,$$

you can rewrite the KVL as

$$V = G_1V+\ldots+G_nV.$$

Dividing both sides of the above equation by $V$ yields the result:

$$G_1+\ldots+G_n = 1.$$